# cannot restart postgres cluster, because of non existant user id, cannot add user with that ID because it exist

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to restart my postgres cluster, but its supposed to be owned by user id that doesnt exist. when I try to add that user, its supposed to be existing.
What can I do from here?

***root@localhost:~# pg_lsclusters***

```
12  main    5432 down   /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12 main.log
```

***root@localhost:~# pg_ctlcluster 12 main restart***

```
Error: The cluster is owned by user id 109 which does not exist
```

***root@localhost:~# sudo adduser -UID 109 postgres***

```
adduser: The GID 109 is already in use.
```

The user should be in group 116 which also doesn't exist.

After re-adding the appropriate user and user group has not helped me to restart the cluster, I simply dropped the cluster and added a new one. Now I have a running postgres cluser again.

```
root@localhost:~# pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log
/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log

root@localhost:~# sudo systemctl stop postgresql@12-main
root@localhost:~# sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 12 main

root@localhost:~# sudo pg_createcluster --start 12 main
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *group* 109 already exists, but the *user* 109 doesn't, so the solution is to create a *new group* with ID 116 and a *new user* with ID 109 in that group:

```bash
groupadd --gid 116 postgres
useradd --gid 116 --no-user-group --uid 109 --home-dir /var/lib/postgresql postgres
```

Next time, don't drop a user you still need...

Comment: Thanks. I (re)-added the user as you suggested. When I want to restart the cluster now, the Error changes to:
Error: The cluster is owned by group id 116 which does not exist

Now I should add a new user group I suppose, would you help me out?

Comment: Perhaps you should call in an expert to salvage your system. I have edited the answer.

Comment: yeah apparently, I have messed up my postgresql service. Adding the group and user works, but I am still not able to restart the service. 
"root@localhost:~# pg_ctlcluster 12 main restart
Job for postgresql@12-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@12-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
"

Comment: I will try to readd the cluster

Comment: That's a pretty useless error from `systemctl`... Have a look at the unit file, try to start the server manually with `pg_ctl`. These activities will perhaps show what is still wrong.

Comment: I was able to get a running cluster again by dropping the old one.